# Disable Button if User Already Exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button in `shortlist.php` file by which i submit new data of specific user through Ajax to MySQL `shortlisted` table.

```
        <button type="button" id="applybutton" class="btn btn-primary" >
            <div class="hidden-xs" id="result">Shortlist</div>
        </button>
```

and it work awesome, but i want to bring a change. Like: On page `shortlist.php` page load I want to check if same UserId exist in `ApplicantId` column`shortlisted` MySQL table. If exist then this button should disable and Shortlist word in button should change to Shortlisted word, and if not then it should be as it is.

**Extra Details:**

- Database Connection Name: $conn
- Database Name: job

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: Do you know how to get the info from the DB?

Comment: @RST Everything is working fine and i can submit data, but the problem is that i don't know that whether this `UserId` data submitted or not because if i submit the data once then for second time the button is active and i can submit for the second time with same data which is not good. Instead i want to disable the button and change the Shortlist word to shortlisted if same `UserId` exist in `ApplicantId` column.

Comment: @Mihailo yes i know.

Comment: on click (when you're sending the first request) disable the button, on success keep it disabled with different text, on error re-enable it.

Comment: You need to show us some code, show us what you've tried and which errors you get.

Comment: @Mihailo Thanks yes you got the point. That is what i want.

Comment: Dear @Hallur, i think it is more than obvious. It can't be described better than that. Please also remove that minus. Thanks

Comment: @Hallur, as i wrote there. I want to disable the button if the same UserId exist in ApplicantId column, if not then it should be as it is - enable.

Comment: I vote down questions that are of bad quality. This meaning any question that doesn't demonstrate any kind of attempt at solving the problem. SO is not a community that has been set in place to do your programming for you.

Comment: @Hallur, sorry for your misunderstanding. This community is here to help each other if we stuck in a problem and it is for learning and helping othere. My question is complete and with quality, if you read it.

Answer (score 0):

while you are sending ajax call, after clicking the button you can disable your button using following.

```
$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
```

to disable the buttons at first when the page is refreshed/loaded you can change your query little bit. left join shortlisted table with your current query. then if you get any value from joined table disable the button.

left join query

```
SELECT profiles.*, shortlisted.ApplicantId FROM profiles LEFT JOIN shortlisted ON profiles.UserId=shortlisted.ApplicantId WHERE profiles.UserId = '$reserver'
```

and change the button to following

```
<button type="button" id="applybutton" class="btn btn-primary" <?=($row['ApplicantId'])?" disabled='disabled':''?> >
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but can you clarify it by writing the exact code. I want to disable the button on page load if UserId exist if not then the button should be enable.

Comment: if you want me write full code, it is a time consuming and hard work. share your code so that i can show what to change.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7z0g6536/ this is my whole code, and i want to disable that shortlist button on page load if current UserId exist in ApplicantId Column.

Answer (score 0):

#### PHP part:

1. Using **PHP** check if the user has an entry in the table.

   > If he does echo a **disabled** attribute inside the button. And provide some info why it's disabled
2. If he does not have an entry, the button is not disabled and the user can submit the form.

   > Upon submission you validate the request (check if he **truly** does not have an entry in the table, because he can easily remove **disabled** in html).

#### Js part:

On submission before sending the ajax request disable the button. And then submit the request with the following logic.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('p.sub_info').text("Form submitting...");
  $('#sub_button').attr("disabled", true);

  $.ajax({
    url: "shortlist.php", 
    success: function(result){
      if(result === true){ // Everything is ok
        $('p.sub_info').text("You're now on the list.");
        $('#sub_button').attr("disabled", true);
      }
      else{ // He did not pass validation
        $('p.sub_info').text("It seems we already have you on the list.");
        $('#sub_button').attr("disabled", true);
      }          
    },
    error: function(result){
      $('p.sub_info').text("Something went wrong.");
      $('#sub_button').attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i couldn't get anything can you please guide me through.

Comment: What part are you confused with?

Comment: I like the php part concept, and i don't know how to write it. This is my whole code https://jsfiddle.net/7z0g6536/.

Comment: You said you knew how to get the info from the DB... Just check if `UserId` is in the table already. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I can get data from MySQL database, but i don't know how to use `if`, and disable the button if UserId exists.

Comment: Ask the DB to get you the row where `UserId = $reserver` if the result is empty you are OK to INSERT the new one, else `return false` or `throw new Exception()`.

Comment: Thanks, i am new and i can't figure it out. sorry

Comment: Ok so do you now understand how to do this?

Comment: I will try, let me see what will be the result, but if you help me through then it might be good. thanks

Comment: @qaisali So how's it going?

Comment: Ahahahahah, I couldn't find any solution I search if statement but no luck.

Comment: Wait you don't know how to use **if** statements?

Comment: :) no sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Why are you apologizing? Listen before you things like this you need to learn the basics. Skipping steps can be really **REALLY** bad. First learn the basics of **procedural** programming, then some **OOP**. And then try to do things like this. Here's a good but a bit outdated tutorial series from [newboston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCUV3iv9xOs&list=PL442FA2C127377F07).

Comment: Btw would you be kind to accept my answer, because I did answer the question you made.

Comment: I gave you step by step instructions. And after a couple of hours of conversation you finally say you don't know ANYTHING about programming. This was a huge waste of my time, and you're rude to top it off. Good luck, you will need it.